# Postman send header and get from httpresponsemessage

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use Postman to make a call to my web api and within Postman pass in some header values. Then within the C# web api I'm trying to get the header values. Probably due to lack of knowledge/understanding I'm struggling to be able to get the header values from HttpResponseMessage.

I set a header in Postman with the key and value.
[image]

I have a delegate that attempts to get the information

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> keys = null;
        if (!request.Headers.TryGetValues("AppData", out keys))
            return null;

        var item = keys.First();
  .....
  }
```

When I debug and put a break at the IEnumerable, the request doesn't have the value I set in the header. What may I be missing?

---

The fix for me.

I was able to get this working. Here is what I discovered and did. The HttpRequestMessage request did in fact contain the header information that I was passing by way of Postman. It seems it depends on where in the process it is captured. In my case this was done from within the global.asax. It seems I was trying to capture the request to soon so the header information wasn't being included. So, I moved the request capture outside the delegate and into a controller and there I had the passed header information.

Comment: postman is making a request - are you proxying it thru an `HttpClient`?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @DanielA.White No, it is not using a proxy

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve ?  Do you want to retrieve request header on server side code ?  OR you want to know how to see response header in postman ?  OR you want to know how to write code in c# to send request header and read respnose headers ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `HttpRequestMessage` stores information about query parameters, i.e. everything after `?` in the url. For instance: `http://foo.bar?name=dummy`.

Secondly if you are sending headers, you should tell your method to perform model binding and use `[FromHeader]`. Ideally it would be something like this:

```
protected override async Task SendAsync([FromHeader] string appData)
{
   await DoCoolStuff(appData);
}
```

Finally, I guess you're missing a port number in your url after `localhost`. It should be something like `localhost:5000`. If you're aiming specific port, you can set it in your `Startup.cs` by adding `.UseUrls("http://*5001")`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Appreciate the info in what the HttpRequestMessage actually stores.

Comment: @MicahMontoya would you mind accepting the answer if it helped to solve your problem?